# Stop k8s cronjob from restarting when manually deleted

Tags: kubernetes

Sometimes I need to keep a k8s CronJob running so temporarily add the common debug command to my template:

```bash
tail -f /dev/null
```

with a spec of:

```yaml
backoffLimit: 3
template:
  spec:
    restartPolicy: Never
```

I then debug and make modifications to the template and then and remove the `tail`, run helm `apply`, and then run `kubectl delete <cronjob pod>` so I can get my new settings applied. However k8s just respawns the old cronjob which has the `tail` in it. I can delete it dozens of times but it doesn't appear the `backoffLimit` counter is incremented since the cronjob never stops respawning.

I've tried using `suspend: true` in the cronjob template which indeed stops the job respawning temporarily, but as soon as i set `suspend: false` again the old template with the debug `tail` in it starts respawning.

Ultimately I have to add an `installed: false` to the template to completely remove the cronjob, then add it back to get the old debug template with `tail` in it cleared out.

Is there a way to get a `kubectl delete`'d cronjob to actually stop respawning, or a better way of debugging cronjobs in general?

Comment: Let me know if the provided info helped you in overcoming the issue, if not share  me the details to troubleshoot the issue further

Comment: I hope the provided information might helped you in overcoming the issue and you can update me if you face any other issues

Answer (score 0):

As you have tried using suspend: true, note that as per this official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#schedule-suspension):

> Executions that are suspended during their scheduled time count as missed jobs. When .spec.suspend changes from true to false on an existing CronJob without a starting deadline, the missed jobs are scheduled immediately.

So some jobs might be recreated so after suspending jobs check :

- For any existing jobs using

  `Kubectl get jobs`
- Manually delete the existing jobs using `kubectl delete job <jobname>`

If above steps didn’t resolve your issues try using `.spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` and `.spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit` as:

```
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  jobTemplate:
    Spec:
```

This field will ensure that the jobs will be deleted after finishing and you can find more details about it from the [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits).